# How to load data in advanced data grid on Scroll

Tags: apache-flex

Hi all i need to load 10 records from database in advanced data grid. After i scroll the advanced data grid. it has to load 11 to 20 records etc.,

How it can be done

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is via ActionScript and event listeners. But this may not be an optimal user experience. Are you trying to separate your records into pages, or do you want to just add more records each time the user scrolls to the bottom.?